# After publishing web site didn't get precompiled files

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I have developed a web site first time when I build and publish web site I got pre-compiled pages.

But when I have made few changes on that and again try to publish it not giving pre-compiled pages at destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the solution, Delete ASP.Net Temporary Files directory's content, do another build, publish your files then.